# Property of non object on form submission

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to figure out what's happening here but for some reason I'm getting an error on the structure here. In my form submission I have an object called subtasks that has a title and instructions:

```
subtasks:
  0:
    instructions:"test",
    title: "title test"
```

And I see it in my consoled when submitted, however, in the controller I get the error "trying to get property 'title' of a non-object" right here:

```
private static function insertTaskSubtasks($taskWebIdentifier, $subtasks) {
    $sql = "CALL INSERT_TASK_SUBTASK ( ? , ? , ? ) ";
    foreach ($subtasks as $subtask) {
        DB::connection('odbc')->statement($sql, [$taskWebIdentifier, $subtask->title, $subtask->instructions]);
    }
}
```

What's going on here exactly? It seems to be coming through in the correct structure for this procedure

Comment: How are you receiving the `$subtasks` data? Probably you should access the info as an array: `$subtask['title']`, `$subtask['instructions']`

Comment: Are you sure that `$subtasks` is an array of objects? What is the output of `Log::info(print_r($subtasks, true))`

Comment: @HCK Thank you, I think that may have resolved my issue but I'm testing now